# A continuous map from  $D$ unit disk, to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

1. $f:D\rightarrow S^1$ is a continuous then $\exists x\in S^1$ such that $f(x)=x$?
2. $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ then same as 1 holdd?
3. $f:E\rightarrow E$ then same as 1 hold? $E=\{(x,y):2x^2+3y^2\le 1\}$

by Fixed point Theorem I know 2,3 are correct, what about 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In #1, you can think of $f: D\rightarrow D$.  The fixed-point theorem says that there exists $x\in D$ so that $f(x) = x$.

In #2, any rotation that is not a complete rotation has no fixed point.

In #3, $E$ is homeomorphic to the unit disk.  It must have a fixed point.

Comment: sorry I do not understand #2 @ncmathsadist

Comment: Simple example $f: S^1 \to S^1$, $f(z) = -z$, has no fixed points.

Comment: By that I mean any rotation that is not a multiple of $2\pi$.